# Does animating the value of a CSS3 transform with javascript rule out hardware acceleration?

Tags: javascript, animation, css, jquery-animate

You can take advantage of hardware accelerated animations by setting an animation duration and setting the initial and final values of the CSS3 transform.

What if, instead of setting an animation duration and using keyframes, you animate the value of the desired CSS3 transform directly with JavaScript? Will you still be taking advantage of hardware acceleration, or is the hardware acceleration ruled out?

Comment: Analysis on why jQuery way is slower than CSS: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/demos/speed.php . The jQuery version doesn't even animate on my dual core CPU when there's too many blocks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is** hardware accelerated, but as Rich mentions, it's easier and more efficient to do it with CSS transitions. The thing is that animating 3d transforms with jQuery is not straightforward, if you do:

```
$('div').animate({
    '-vendor-transform' : "translate3d(100px,0,0)";
}, 500)
```

It doesn't work. Even if you do:

```
$('div').css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0,0,0)");
alert($('div').css("-webkit-transform"))
```

You don't get back `translate3d(0,0,0)`, you get `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 0)`

So you must write a lot of custom animation code involving matrices just to get things moving on screen.

Here is a custom animated 3d transform example: http://www.eleqtriq.com/wp-content/static/demos/2010/rotation/, take a look at the source code to see if it's the level of javascript you are comfortable with.

Comment: Wow!! So the values of the `-webkit-transform: rotate3D(...)` are animated with javascript, but the whole thing is accelerated with the GPU? What about properties like `top`, or `left`? I'm under the impression that if you animate those properties with javascript they won't be GPU accelerated unless you apply `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` to trigger GPU acceleration. Is that right?

Comment: No, even if you apply `translate3d` and then animate `left` with jquery, the gpu won't kick in. Here are some test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/zAgpd/, the difference is more evident in Safari.

Comment: To be honest, I can't even notice any difference in performance on my computer. They all seem to perform just as euqally smooth. So just to verify, both `#jqhardware` and `#hardware` are hardware accelerated?

Comment: Duopixel, I'm comfortable with that level of (javascript) programming, but tell me this: Which of the three samples in your jsfiddle example are hardware accelerated (by Webkit)?

Answer (score 3):

It won't be hardware accelerated for webkit browsers unless you use transitions. Also, only 3d transforms are accelerated, so a quick way to ensure that the element is going to use the 3d rendering tree if it's avaliable is to add:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

The reason transforms are quick by the way, is because by definition they don't affect any other elements - this means the browser doesn't need to repaint the whole window, just the part that's being transformed.

The old way of animating should really be considered obsolete, as it is much less efficient than transitions, and generally has a lower framerate, particularly on iOS.

Comment: So, for example, the a skew transform won't be acelerated without using that `transform3d: translate(0,0,0);` trick?

Comment: Not sure on skew - I've only ever used translate in production use. I assume so, but might be wrong.

Comment: Rich meant `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`.

Comment: I'd emphasize that what you say relates to Webkit. For example Trident accelerates everything, acceleration in Gecko has also nothing to do with 3D transforms.

Comment: Ooops - just changed that. I'm so used to webkit being the only browser that does has support for both I forget the others have caught up!

Comment: @duri Trident accelerates all javascript animations with the GPU, even simple ones like animating `top` or `left`? If so, that is amazing, and that is what WebKit needs.

Comment: @trusktr Yes, the rendering engine has been rewritten in IE9 so the entire rendering - `<canvas>` drawing, `<video>` decoding, even rendering of the most basic websites (naturally, including `-ms-transition` effects in IE10) is done through GPU. And yes, this is amazing, but it requires large changes in rendering engine and is not possible without months of finding and removing bugs.

Comment: That is true (that it would take lots of time). This is something that I would have set out to do from the very beginning if I was making a browser. Nowadays, pretty much everyone has hardware acceleration! Currently, it seems backwards: browsers implemented with software acceleration and now hardware acceleration support is being added. It seems it should have been Hardware Acceleration first, then software fallback for users without the GPU/hardware.