# CSS: is transition: left/top GPU accelerated?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

I know that you can force GPU acceleration to achieve smooth animation of elements across the screen by applying a transition to the 'transform' property, e.g.:

```
elem.style.transition = 'all 3s ease-out';
elem.style.transform = 'translateX(600px)';
```

But I was wondering what would happen if you replaced the second line with:

```
elem.style.left = '600px';
```

Would/could GPU acceleration kick in for the "left" (or "top") property, or does it have to be on the transform property? It seems to me that it should be GPU accelerate-able, but I can't glean a final answer from any of the documentation I've read.

Comment: For your question to have any chance of being answered, you'd have to narrow it down to a specific version of a specific browser on a specific OS with a specific graphics sub-system.  All of those things can affect the answer because this is not something spelled out in a specification - it's up to the implementors of a specific browser on a specific OS/piece of hardware.  There is evidence that some browsers use the GPU to accelerate some CSS directives and not others in some circumstances, but even that can only be talked about in the above terms.

Comment: Well, I'm not so sure about that... I'm not looking for an answer for a specific OS/GPU/browser/etc., I'm looking for a generalized answer as many different OS/GPUs/browsers/etc might be accessing my site. If the answer ends up being "it depends -- all OS's/browsers/etc handle this differently, so don't depend on it", then that would be a satisfying answer. Either way, it seems like someone's already responded from a differing perspective.

Comment: The answer you checked answers your question for some versions of one or possiblity two browsers when operating on some types of hardware.  Perhaps that's what you were looking for, but your question was a lot more general than that which is why I said it has to be answered in the context of a particular implementation on a particular piece of hardware.   There's absolutely nothing that says that setting the left property with javascript and triggering a CSS transition can't or won't use hardware acceleration - therefore the question is whether ANY browser in any circumstance currently does.

Comment: Just to show you how complicated this can get, the same browser core (Safari) running on a Mac, and iPhone 2, an iPhone 3s and an iPod Touch can all offer different levels of hardware acceleration on different CSS3 transitions.  It's very implementation-specific even in the same browser family and even more so from one browser to the next and one browser version to the next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not accelerated. You have to use the specific CSS3 properties for it to be accelerateable. I think you'll find these links interesting:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/

http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

[Does animating the value of a CSS3 transform with javascript rule out hardware acceleration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783973/does-animating-the-value-of-a-css3-transform-with-javascript-rule-out-hardware-a)

Comment: Great! Seems like this question was answered in a followup comment in the last link you posted. Thanks!

Comment: @knutole Very nice link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The consensus I've gathered is that only the `translate3d` property is hardware accelerated on mobile devices such as Mobile Safari.

[Further Reading](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/).

Comment: Yes, this was the very page that inspired me to post this question. It contrasts the timer-based approach of changing left/top every few milliseconds with the CSS3 transition-based approach using transition/transform, but unfortunately it leaves out the combination of left/top with 'transition'.