# Use GPU Accelerated CSS to move the background

Tags: css, gpu

For couple of days I have been trying to find out how to use the gpu accelerated css to move the background image on a web page. What is the code that I need to use to be able to do that
Based on certain information I think that the transform3d(0,0,0) does that but i am not sure what to do next?
Would really appreciate if you could help me out here

Comment: Thank you Felipeals, that's true it's just I am trying to find out how to implement it on a background image and also do I need to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

trasform3d will *likely* be GPU accelerated in a *few* browsers used *in 2015*, yes. Other than that, many mileages will vary!

You can read [latest entry from Calendar Perfplanet from 2014](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2014/hardware-accelerated-css-the-nice-vs-the-naughty/) and follow the first links (at least SmashingMag and CSStriggers).

There are very good DevTools in Chrome available to webdevs that will show you how long is a repaint, analyze it and then, well, trial and error.

EDIT: topic still relevant because its answers are general though 3 years old: [What exact parts of CSS3 are GPU accelerated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148012/what-exact-parts-of-css3-are-gpu-accelerated?rq=1)