# CSS : Is there a way to know if GPU is being used?

Tags: css, css-transitions, gpu, css-transforms

I know some [CSS properties, on some browsers, on some OS, can trigger GPU acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148012/what-exact-parts-of-css3-are-gpu-accelerated#12148329).

Is there a way to see, somewhere within the browsers' debugging tools, if the GPU is actually being used or not ?

Comment: Unfortunately my network is blocking the images but this might help : https://blog.mozilla.org/joe/2010/11/10/how-to-tell-if-youre-using-hardware-acceleration/

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Not really what I was looking for though. I was hoping allowing me to see if transition A or transform B is actually using the GPU. Thanks anyway !

Comment: This question is covered in this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26371807