# How to manipulate CSS3 3D Transform with js/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I want to create a simple script that rotates a DIV in 3D perspective, so I want to gradually manipulate div's *transform* property. It's initially set to `perspective(500px) rotateY(44deg)`, but when I try to get the property value with jQuery's .css(), it only returns the `matrix3d` property, leaving me with no direct access to *rotateY()*. How can I easily access and adjust transform's attributes such as *rotateY()* with js/jQuery?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be writing something that needs to keep reading from the CSS. Why not keep track of your values in the JS and only write to the properties?

Comment: I think it would be hard as I'm aiming to animate dynamically loaded elements... Anyway the main hurdle for me is the lack of direct access to very specific properties of the transform, such as "rotateY()"

Comment: In that case I think you're going to have to do some math with the matrix. [Here's a similar question with an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270612/get-element-moz-transformrotate-value-in-jquery).

Comment: Have you looked at any of the available jQuery 3D transform plugins? Related: [Are JS-animated transforms still hardware-accelerated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8783973/1048572)